# python 3.7.6 pip setup.py test with ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

my `setup.py` is like below:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

tests_require = ['pytest-env', 'pytest-mock', 'pytest-cov', 'pytest-xdist', 'pytest', 'mock', 'moto<=1.3.10']

setup(
    name='repo_name',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='repo_name',
    keywords=['?'],
    packages=find_packages('src', exclude=['tests', 'venv']),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    package_data={'': ['schema/*.yaml']},
    install_requires=[
        'boto3<=1.10.19',
        'requests<=2.22.0',
        'jsonschema<=3.0.1',
        'objectpath<=0.6.1',
        'pyyaml<=5.1.1',
        'sqlalchemy<=1.3.5',
        'psycopg2-binary<=2.8.3',
        'auth-client<=1.0.23',   # internal package
        'policy_client<=1.0.9',  # internal package
        'audit-client<=1.1.20',  # internal package
        'flask<=1.1.1',
        'click<=7.0',
        'Werkzeug<=0.15.5',
        'itsdangerous<=1.1.0',
        'Jinja2<=2.10.1',
        'MarkupSafe<=1.1.1',
        'structlog<=19.2.0',
        'python-rapidjson<=0.9.1'
    ],
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=tests_require,
    extras_require={'test': tests_require},
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False
)
```

When I run `python setup.py test`, it will always reinstall the most of the packages that I already installed into `.eggs` folder, which I understand. While it's installing the package with different versions that I provided in the `install_requires` section, which results in below error:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.25.10 (/Users/***/Desktop/repo/.eggs/urllib3-1.25.10-py3.7.egg), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1'), {'requests'})
```

I have to pin the `requests` version to 2.22.0 which requires `urllib3` version no larger than 1.25, which caused my issue. So, is there anyway I can pin the `urllib3` version in somewhere so when it runs, it will only install the provided version? I have tried to add the urllib3 version in `install_requires`, `tests_require` and in `requirements.txt`, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolve to simply replace `python setup.py test` to be `pip instll -e . [test]`, and then `pytest` directly.

It will still install all the `tests_require` packages and then run `pytest` directly. Instead of going through all the list packages and find the best match versions for all packages.

**UPDATES:**

The real problem is I did not remove the old **.eggs/** and **venv/** folder when I made the packages version change. So the solution is updating the `requests` version to be 2.21.0 in the setup.py file, then remove the **.eggs/** and **venv/** folder and rerun everything.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want to hear but... `setup_requires` and `tests_require` are *deprecated*. Although they (probably) still work (mostly) fine, you might want to look for alternative solutions. As far as I know the most common alternative solutions are to use [*Tox*](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) instead of `tests_require` and [*PEP 517*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) to replace `setup_requires`.

In your case, it seems that your usage of `setup_requires` is only a consequence of your usage of `tests_require`. So by switching to something like *Tox* you get rid of both `tests_require` and `setup_requires`.

Comment: we are bind to use python 3.7.* version currently, and these are still in the scope. Tox is good while we cant use it as company regulation. Any idea to keep my current structure and resolve the problem?

Comment: I do not understand how the fact that you are bound to Python 3.7 plays a role in this issue. Too bad you can't use tox, but it isn't strictly necessary it is just a common recommendation. Anyway you found a solution, I'm glad!